# Can overcooked caramel be harmful?

Tags: caramelization

Ok, here's the situation. I put a pan of water and sugar on a medium high flame and went away. Some time later I found a smoldering black mass overflowing the pan. It took some time to clean up (anybody know how to remove burnt caramel from stainless steel?).

I threw the burnt caramel away, but later started wondering. There is a sweet called 'carbon' and I have no idea how it's made, but it looks the same as what was in the pan... So there's the question. How is 'carbon' made?

**Edit** The question was whether the burnt sugar is edible. The answer of course is: no.

Comment: I just read that 'carbon' is made from a sugar/water mix (80/20) with black coloring mixed with a caramel.

Comment: My black smoldering mass has been adequately disposed of...

Comment: What exactly is the question? Your title doesn't seem to match the main content of your post, and you also partially answer one of your questions in your comments.

Comment: A method that could work when cleaning your pot is scrubbing it with a lump of sugar.

Comment: For the record, never, ever leave caramel unattended. It boils at high temperatures and if someone were to 'just dip their finger in it' or a kid were to come along and knock it off, they'd be very badly burnt.

Comment: Something burnt is never healthy.

Comment: not true, Mien. It'll taste bad, but isn't necessarily bad for your health (not sure about burnt sugar). Charcoal for example is burnt wood, and is used as a medicine to cure diarrhea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is called poured sugar oil moulds(rings) that you want to use ant shape is okay then use 2 lbs sugar,1 lb water, 6.55 ounces of glucose  and food colouring if you want.make a syrup with the three and then boil until it reaches 260F add food colouring continue to boil until temp. reaches 330F  plunge the pot into a cold water bath to stop the cooking.remove from water and let stand 2-3 minutes to thicken. Pour mixture into moulds until 1/4 inch thick. Once edges have setenough remove the ring. Use a little reheated sugar to attached pieces together like a glue.this can be used as a base for any center piece you want to create with other sugar pieces